# Why does the console close after my last input?

Tags: c#, console

My program allows the user to put in 20 prices and to display the average of those values. Why does the console close after I enter my last input? Below is the code I'm running:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace machineproblem4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            double average = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t         INPUT PRICES  \n");
            int[] price = new int[20];
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t  Please enter 20 prices \n");

            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 20; ctr++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter price {0} :   ", ctr + 1);
                price[ctr] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            }

            // [...calculate sum...]

            //average 

            Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("||average of the prices||");
            average = sum / 20;
            Console.WriteLine("average of the prices:   {0}", average);

            //more code that outputs statistics about the inputs

            //exit

            //Edit: This is what fixed my problem
            Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit ..");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The way this is phrased is somewhat unhelpful. The real question you have is "Why does the console close after I enter my last input?", but the only question you have in the body of your question is, "Am I missing something?" I'm going to edit it to clarify the question

Answer (score 2):

use   `Console.Readline();`

Read(), ReadLine() and ReadKey() are basically static methods, and they comes under the Console class. That's why we use these methods like:

`Console.Read():`-- method accept the String and return the integer.

`Console.ReadLine()`:--method accept the String and return string .

`Console.ReadKey()`:--method accept the Character and also return Character.

That's why we mostly use the Console.ReadKey() method, for come back to source code from output window .

Because when we only press the character we directly come on source code. If you will use the Console.Read() and Console.ReadLine method then 
you need to press Enter, come back to the source code rather then any character.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a Console.Read() at the last statement. You can also place a breakpoint at your last statement

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
Console.Readline();
```

at the end of your main function, so it waits until you press enter before it closes.

Comment: Where ?? be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is not a good idea to wait for user input from a console application. This is okay for debugging, but not definitely for release.
So, first find out if your application is in debug or release config using

```
private static bool IsDebug()
{
    object[] customAttributes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DebuggableAttribute), false);
    if ((customAttributes != null) && (customAttributes.Length == 1))
    {
        DebuggableAttribute attribute = customAttributes[0] as DebuggableAttribute;
        return (attribute.IsJITOptimizerDisabled && attribute.IsJITTrackingEnabled);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then use,

```
if (IsDebug())
    Console.Readline();
```

This eliminates the need to edit the code for different build configurations. Alternative is to put a breakpoint and debug the console app, as suggested by @Erwin

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers actually directly answer the question of why this is happening. The reason why the console is closing after your last input is that the rest of the code runs very quickly and when it reaches the end of your program, the console closes. This is correct behavior and should be expected when running a console application. As the other answers have stated, you can work around this by requiring a final input before closing the console, but that is all it is, a work around.

If you were to output to a text file rather than just the console, you would see that all of the output is generated as you would expect. The console output and close is just too fast for you to see it without some sort of pause in the code.

Additionally, a solution that has not been mentioned yet is to run the project from Visual Studio without debugging, which will automatically output "Press any key to continue..." when it finishes processing before closing the console. That way you can see what it is outputting without extraneous code that you wouldn't want to have in production code.